# Get Specific Data Structure with WooCommerce Order items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

For one order placed and that order is having 3 products I should need to get a data structure formatted like:

```
[items] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [sku] => Product 1 sku
        [qty] => Product 1 qty
        [price] => Product 1 price
        [weight] =>
        [discount] =>
        [line_ref] =>
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [sku] => Product 2 sku
        [qty] => Product 2 qty
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [sku] => Product 3 sku
        [qty] => Product 3 qty
    )

)
```

Here is my code:

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
// Get the order ID
$order_id = $order->get_id();

// Get data from Items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item_values ) {  

    $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); // the Product id
    $product = $item_values->get_product(); // the WC_Product object
    $item_data = $item_values->get_data();

     $item = array(array(
        'sku'       => $product->get_sku(),
        'qty'       => $item_data['quantity'],
        'price'     => $product->get_price(),
        'weight'    => '',
        'discount'  => '',
        'line_ref'  => ''
        ),
        array(
        'sku'       => $product->get_sku(),
        'qty'       => $item_data['quantity'],
        )
     );

}
print_r($item);
```

How can I achieve this?

I am getting the only data of very first product present in an Order.
And if I do print_r($item); within foreach loop then it repeats the whole data depending on number of products in an Order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
// Get an instance of the order Object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get the order ID
$order_id = $order->get_id();

// Initialising
$items_data = array(); 
$count = 0;

// Loop through Order items
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {  
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // the Product id
    $product    = $item->get_product(); // the WC_Product object
    $item_data  = $item->get_data(); // The line item unprotected data (array)

    if( $count === 0 ) {
        $items_data[] = array(
            'sku'       => $product->get_sku(),
            'qty'       => $item->get_quantity(),
            'price'     => $product->get_price(),
            'weight'    => '',
            'discount'  => '',
            'line_ref'  => ''
        );
    } else {
        $items_data[] = array(
            'sku'       => $product->get_sku(),
            'qty'       => $item->get_quantity(),
        );
    }
    $count++;
}
$output = array('items' => $items_data );

// Testing output
print_r($output);
```

It should better work as you like.

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec , I got the exact solution I was looking for.